# How do I create a new column in a df that is either 0 or 1 based off of other column values?

Tags: python

I would like to make a new column in my df that is based off of values in other columns. I have read endless tutorials, but nothing has worked for me yet. I would like a new column "treatment" that is assigned a value of 0 or 1 based off if the value from the column "week" is between the values from columns `week_begin` and `week_end`.

This what I did:

```
def conditions(row):
    if row['week'] >= 'week_begin" & row['week'] <= 'week_end':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

union_accident['treatment'] = union_accident.apply(conditions, axis=1)

union_accident.head()

This returns the error:

```
 '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: vectorized solution: `df['treatment'] = df[['week','week_begin','week_end']].apply(lambda x: 1 if x[1]<x[0]<x[2] else 0)`

Answer (score 0):

your immediate error is because you're using single quotes everywhere and have a typo double quote at the end of `week_begin` on line 2.

But, fixing that, you can easily do this by directly comparing the columns to each other! No need for `.apply`

The sneaky `.astype(int)` will change this column from a boolean type (True/False) to a numeric type with values of (1/0)

```py
union_accident['treatment'] = (
      union_accident['week_begin'] <= union_accident['week']
    & union_accident['week'] <= union_accident['week_end']
).astype(int)
```

But that's a lot of repetition of `union_accident` right there- you can also use the `.eval` method to do this in a much less verbose manner:

```py
union_accident['treatment'] = union_accident.eval(
    '(week_begin <= week) & (week <= week_end)'
).astype(int)
```

Comment: Cameron Riddell you are absolutely amazing! Thanks I learned a lot!

Comment: Of course! Glad this helped you- if this answered your question, would you mind selecting this answer as the "correct" one? That way, anyone else who has the same/similar question can quickly find an appropriate answer!

Answer (score 0):

**You can use slicing like this,Just Change the**

> Condition B>=3

to your Condition, i have Written it like this for generalization purposes

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])

df.loc[df["B"]>=3,"NewColumn"]=0

df.loc[df["B"]<=3,"NewColumn"]=1




    A   B   NewColumn
0   0   1   1.0
1   2   3   1.0
2   4   5   0.0
3   6   7   0.0
4   8   9   0.0
```

For More Information
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy